# Simplifying algebraic expression with fraction of polynomials

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I cannot seem to find a way to simplify the following expression:
$$\frac{9{a}^{4}-{a}^{2}{ b  }^{ 4  }  +16 { b  }^{ 8  }    }{ 3 { a  }^{ 2  }  -5a { b  }^{ 2  }  +4 { b  }^{ 4  }    }$$
I have tried factoring by $a$ and rewriting the division as multiplication with inverse.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Try following this guidelines to get help in this forum. For example, there's a section called "Tag your question correctly". This question is NOT about linear algebra.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, I had a hard time finding the appropriate tag for this question, maybe elementary-number-theory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straightforward solution, simply use long division.

\begin{array}{rrrrrrr}
& & 3a^2 &+5a b^2&+4b^4&&\\
\hline
3a^2-5ab^2+4b^4 & | & 9a^4 & & -a^2b^4 &&+ 16 b^8\\
&&-9a^4&+15a^3b^2&-12a^2b^4\\
\hline
&&&15a^3b^2&-13a^2b^4&&+16b^8\\
&&&-15a^3b^2&+25a^2b^4&-20ab^6\\
\hline
&&&&12a^2b^4&-20a b^6&+16b^8\\
&&&&-12a^2b^4&+20ab^6&-16b^8\\
\hline
&&&&&&0
\end{array}

Answer (score 1):

The numerator $9a^4 - a^2 b^4 + 16b^8$ factorises as
$(3a^2+4b^4+5ab^2)(3a^2+4b^4−5ab^2)$.

Thus, when the $3a^2+4b^4−5ab^2\not=0$,
$$\frac{9a^4 - a^2 b^4 + 16b^8}{3a^2+4b^4−5ab^2}=   3a^2+4b^4+5ab^2$$

Comment: ah okay so the trick was to note the relation between numerator and divisor

Comment: Yes, the first thing I noticed was that we have $9a^4$ and $16b^8$, which are $(3a^2)^2$ and $(4b^4)^2$ respectively, which raised my suspicions, given the expression in the denominator.